# Use a rails method outside of rails

Tags: ruby

I highly doubt it is possible but thought I'd post and ask to confirm.

I have written a very small ruby script to bulk rename a folderful of files but I need to use Rail's parameterize method on the filenames. I am not inside a rails project as I am running it from within the directory of files I wish to rename. I also do not wish to make this a fully blown rails app.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Neil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is defined in ActiveSupport (part of Rails). You can use ActiveSupport outside of Rails. Just require the lib

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

# now parameterize method should be available
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Just tried and get this:

/Users/{user}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
 from /Users/{user}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'

Comment: Is active_support installed? Run `gem install active_support`.

Comment: The gem is named `activesupport`, even though the requireable path is `active_support`.